Get Global key error while using Obx inside GetMaterialApp with getx
I'm getting the error as I have used Obx inside GetMaterialApp

Error: A GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child
list.

This is my main.dart code
final appNavigator = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

return SessionTimeoutManager(
      sessionConfig: sessionConfig,
      child: ScreenUtilInit(
        useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
        designSize: const Size(360, 690),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: BaseStrings.appName,
            navigatorKey: appNavigator,
            navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[
              GetObserver((p0) {
                var route = Get.currentRoute;
                "route--$route".toLog;
                if(route == Routes.LOGIN || route == 
                 Routes.DASH_BOARD_PAGE){
                  currentRoute1.value = true;
                } else {
                  currentRoute1.value = false;
                }
              }),
            ],
            getPages: Routes.pages,
            initialRoute: Routes.SPLASH_SCREEN,
            defaultTransition: Transition.native,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Obx(() {
                return Scaffold(body: child, floatingActionButton: currentRoute1.value ?     FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {  }, child: const Icon(Icons.messenger),) : null,);
              });
              },
          );
        },
      ),
    );

I have try to add keys to particular scaffold try to add home but it does not works.
